# Chrooting a users login

Tags: linux, unix, rhel5

I want to limit certain users on my system to a subset of commands and have absolutely no access to the rest of the system. I figure chrooting is the way to solve this but I only know how to chroot a ftp user. Can this be done for normal shell users and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) simplifies it.

*Jailkit is a set of utilities to limit user accounts to specific files using chroot() and or specific commands. Setting up a chroot shell, a shell limited to some specific command, or a daemon inside a chroot jail is a lot easier and can be automated using these utilities.*

Answer (score 0):

Please use chroot with extreme caution, it's well known that it doesn't provide the complete protection it seems to.

[chroot limitations from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chroot&oldid=295790140#Limitations)

I remember a debate on the LKML about fixing "bugs" in chroot that allowed users to escape; kernel developers have answered that chroot is not intended to be a security mechanism.